# crontab @reboot starting an UI Application

Tags: cron, mono

I was able to do this until I downloaded the latest raspberry pi image.

It is a DotNET WinForm application.

Started in crontab using @reboot /home/pi/auto.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/test
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
mono disp.exe 2>/tmp/tmp.log
```

The error that I saw in /tmp/log is:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display (X-Server required. Check your DISPLAY environment variable)
Parameter name: Display
```

Comment: So, crontab was faster than X.  You'd better define this as a service that depends on X, via your init system.

Comment: Gerard, may I know how to set crontab depends on X? I seems like I can't do that inside my script, I have waited for 1 min inside my script, but X is still not running

Comment: That's not what crontab is made for.   Either you let your init system handle it (and tell it your service depends on X), or add your script to the xinitrc, which will only run when X is started.