# How to wait for X-Server to init before crontab

Tags: raspbian, cron

Kindly refer to my problem at: [crontab @reboot starting an UI Application](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83445/crontab-reboot-starting-an-ui-application)

I tried to use sleep in my script. It won't work.

May I know how can I wait for X to start before running my crontab?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)
You have decided `crontab` is the solution to your unstated problem, and want us to debug it.

Comment: You asked for `crontab` but that isn't the solution for your problem. Raspbian comes with `systemd`. As [_@Gerard H. Pille_ already stated in his comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/83445/79866) you should make a service to start with `systemd`, maybe `After graphical.target`.

Answer (score 1):

In my message there is a link to my original question, because someone pointed to me that it is crontab issue, that is why I ask here.

Anyway, I have found the answer.

Instead of using "sudo crontab -e"

I just have to use "crontab -e" (without sudo).

The crontab for a user pi runs after X. while crontab for sudo runs before it.

Comment: Nothing like a question you learn to answer yourself :)